# For a input word count all combinations of words.

Tags: permutations, combinations

For an input, word find all combinations of a word with a limit as:

1. Starts with consonants
2. Does not have 2 consecutive consonants
3. Does not have 2 consecutive vowels

Comment: How long can the word be?

Comment: @Harnak Lets say length of the input word is 100

Comment: Consider that, because of the rules you provided, odd positions must be consonants and even positions must be vowels.

Comment: @Harnak thanks. Can you explain the logic little bit. It will be help.